# JavaScript validation in html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

With my page I need to enter several things like title, content, picture etc. This information are sent to script.php and I need to validate those things with php but i get error.

This is how I include JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/form-validation.js"></script>
```

In head i write JS:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function(event)
    </script>
```

And this is form in html:

```
 <form name = "my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method = "POST" action = "skripta.php">
<div class="form-group row  ">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <span id="porukaTitle" class="bojaPoruke"></span> 
                <label  for="naslov">Naslov</label>
            <input  type="text"  name="naslov" class="form-control" id="naslov">
            </div>
 <div class="form-group row ">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Ucitaj"  id="submit"/>
                </div>
</form>
```

But I get this error in browser console:
[image]

When I press submit button page goes to skripta.php where I display page with php.
I'm using xampp !

Comment: First you probably needs to fix this line

`document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function(event)`

    In order the get submit button try `document.querySelector('[type="submit"]')`

    I your example its looks the function body is missing, you can try something like this

    `document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', () => {...})`

This is only going to send your form, but you need to prevent default form behavior, submit the form using for example fetch api, and you do not mention the validation that need to be applied

Answer (score 0):

add javascript validation script at the end of `body` tag

and also use `onload` like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // validation code here
        // if validation is successful
        $("form").submit(); // Submit the form
    })
});
```

You have added script in head, it should be actually added at the end of page load, When your selected element is loaded in DOM.

Also you are posting form to php page so when you'll submit page it'll get redirect to other page and your javascript `onSubmit` will never be called
Instead what you can do is add `onClick` function like I explained and do your validation part inside and once all data is validated you can call `submit()` to route the page to php file.

Comment: Im using xampp to upload that and now it gets me some errors that he cant upload these

Comment: @Zvone I did not understand what you are saying.......I have also updated the code please check.